# Content Translation doesn't trigger with language switcher

Tags: i18n-l10n

My basic page content type is set to use content translation. When looking at the taxonomy term view, switching languages works fine. When looking at a basic page, the language switcher only changes the **UI**. The `URL alias` is dropped and the translated content fails to load.

How do I **resolve** this so the language switcher will switch to the translated node?